# Crear ventana secundaria y poner un Label dentro usando una función

Tags: python, tkinter

Apenas estoy aprendiendo Python, y creé un botón que al oprimirlo me manda a una función llamada `ingresar()` y que se encarga de crear una nueva ventana con un label dentro.

El problema es que cuando corro el programa y me manda a la nueva ventana, el label aparece en la primera ventana, no en la nueva. Aquí está mi código:

```
def ingresar():
    ventanaIngresar=Tk()
    ventanaIngresar.geometry("350x300")
    ventanaIngresar.title("Ingresar")

    lbltipo_inversion=Label(text="Tipo de inversion",font=("Agency FB",14)).place(x=50,y=50)

    ventanaIngresar.mainloop()
```

y este es mi botón:

```
btnIngresar=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Ingresar",command=ingresar,
                                font=("Agency FB",14), width=10).place(x=130,y=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas principales:

- **No deberías tener más de una instancia de `tkinter.TK` en un mismo proceso**, sobretodo si interaccionan entre sí. Todo widget en una app se organiza dentro de un árbol que solo puede tener una ventana principal y por tanto controlados por un solo *mainloop*. Instanciar `tkinter.TK` no implica solo crear una ventana, inicializa el framework por completo, e incluye su propio intérprete Tcl asociado. Técnicamente es posible tener varias instancias de `TK` pero raramente está justificado, suele causar problemas y una sobrecarga raramente necesaria. Además, cada instancia de `TK` es totalmente independiente, sus widget no son compartidos por el resto y no deben interaccionar entre sí de forma directa.

  Cuando necesites crear una ventana secundaria el procedimiento debería ser usar [`tkinter.Toplevel`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html), no crear una nueva instancia de `TK` (a no ser que la lances en otro proceso por otras cuestiones de implementación, por ejemplo).
- A tus widgets de la ventana secundaria debes pasarles la instancia de la ventana secundaria como padre, en caso contrario no se van a mostrar en ella.

Además de lo anterior considera tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- No se debe por norma general usar la forma `from modulo import *` para importar una librería. Es una mala práctica y solo en casos muy concretos está justificado. Además de poblar innecesariamente el espacio de nombres actual, puede crear conflictos con nombres de otras librerías o definidos en el propio módulo y ,sobre todo, dificulta la legibilidad del código (algo muy importante en el *zen* de Python)
- Cuando se hace algo como `lbl = Label(root, text="Hola")).place(x=50,y=50)`, el valor de la variable `lbl` es el retorno del método `place`, es decir `None`. Si no vas a usar esa variable simplemente no la crees, haz solo:

  ```
  Label(root, text="Hola")).place(x=50,y=50)
  ```

  S tienes que usar la referencia del widget con posterioridad, separa su instanciación de la llamada a `place`, `pack` o `grid`:

  ```
  lbl = Label(root, text="Hola"))
  lbl.place(x=50,y=50)
  ```

  De esta forma `lbl` hace referencia a la instancia del `Label`.

Te dejo un ejemplo usando tu código como base junto a `Toplevel`:

```
import tkinter as tk


def ingresar():
    ventanaIngresar = tk.Toplevel(ventanaPrincipal)
    ventanaIngresar.title("Ingresar")
    ventanaIngresar.geometry("350x300")
    tk.Label(ventanaIngresar, text="Tipo de inversion",
             font=("Agency FB", 14)).place(x=50, y=50)

ventanaPrincipal = tk.Tk()
ventanaPrincipal.geometry('380x200')
tk.Button(ventanaPrincipal, text="Ingresar", command=ingresar,
          font=("Agency FB", 14), width=10).place(x=130, y=30)
ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()
```

> **Nota:** Si se usa Python 2.x  cambiar el *import* por `import Tkinter as tk`

Comment: Se puede cerrar la ventana principal después de darle clic al botón?