# ¿Como llamar otra ventana? en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, script

tengo un problema al momento de llamar otra ventana desde la ventana principal, he creado el siguientes script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

#FUNCIONES:
#Menu Principal
def menu():

    try:
        ent1.get() == int(ent1.get())

        if ent1.get() == 1:
            vsismorresistente()

        elif ent1.get() == 2:
            vperf_suelos()

        elif ent1.get() == 3:
            vz_sismica()

        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir la opción correcta")

    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showwarning ("Error", "Escribir solo números enteros.")

def salir():
    vprincipal.destroy()

def vsismorresistente():
    vprincipal.withdraw()
    v_sism_rres = tk.Toplevel()
    v_sism_rres.title("ZONAS SISMORRESISTENTE")
    v_sism_rres.geometry("550x500+0+0")
    v_sism_rres.configure(background = "light sky blue")
    v_sism_rres.mainloop()

def vperf_suelos():
    v_suelos = tk.Toplevel()
    v_suelos.title("PERFILES DE SUELOS")
    v_suelos.geometry("550x500+0+0")
    v_suelos.configure(background = "light sky blue")
    v_suelos.mainloop()

#Configuración de la ventana
vprincipal = tk.Tk()
vprincipal.title("SISMICIDAD")
vprincipal.geometry("550x500")
vprincipal.configure(background = "light sky blue")

#ETIQUETAS:
#Menu Principal:
...

#ENTRADAS:
#Menu Principal:
ent1 = tk.Entry(vprincipal)
ent1.pack(pady = 1, ipady = 5)

#BOTONES:
#Boton para abrir opciones:
botonmenu = tk.Button(vprincipal, text = "Aceptar", fg = "black", command = menu)
botonmenu.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

botonsalir = tk.Button(vprincipal, text = "Salir", fg = "black", command = salir)
botonsalir.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

vprincipal.mainloop()
```

Al correr el script y poner el numero para elegir la opción, no me bota ningún error pero me sale el mensaje de error `messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir la opción correcta")`.

Lo que deseo es que me abra otra ventana al colocar opciones de 1 al 3 en la entrada, as cuales son la ventana de SISMORRESISTENTE (vsismorresistent) y PERFILES DE SUELO (v_suelo).

Comment: Miguel, el tipo de ent1.get(), es str. Conviertelo a int.

Comment: El tipo ent1.get() es el nombre de la entrada, no es el tipo de numerico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- `ent1.get()` retorna una cadena (`str`) con el contenido en ese instante del `Entry`.
- `ent1.get() == int(ent1.get())` no tiene sentido alguno, `ent1.get()` retorna una cadena como se ha comentado y `int(ent1.get())` retorna un entero (si el contenido del Entry es una cadena que representa un entero válido) o una excepción `ValueError`. Por lo tanto, la línea se reduce a **comparar** (operador de igualdad `==`) una cadena con un entero lo que siempre es `False`, pero además como la comparación no está dentro de un condicional o ciclo carece de utilidad.
- Como `get` retorna una cadena las comparaciones `if ent1.get() == 1` y similares **son siempre falsas** porque son objetos de distinta clase no asimilables entre si. Esta es la raíz principal de tu problema, o comparas con una cadena:

  ```
  if ent1.get() == "1":
  ```

  o haces el casting a `int` antes :

  ```
  entry_value = int(ent1.get())

  if ent1.get() == 1:
     vsismorresistente()

  elif entry_value == 2:
      vperf_suelos()

  ...
  ```
- Es buena práctica y bastante sano colocar dentro del bloque `try` exclusivamente aquello que pueda generar las excepciones que queremos manejar. Para el resto mejor usar el bloque `else` que solo se ejecuta sy el `try` no falla.
- Por otro lado, **no debes tener más de una instancia de `tkinter.Tk` y un  mainloop** en una aplicación. Para crear ventanas secundarias usa `tkinter.Toplevel` como haces, pero no llames al método `mainloop`, esto creará otro ciclo infinito dentro del que ya existe y eso siempre es una mala idea. Simplemente pasa al constructor `Toplevel` la referencia a la ventana principal y se usará el mainloop de ésta:

  - [Crear ventana secundaria y poner un Label dentro usando una función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/137975/15089)

Con todo, el código debería quedar:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def menu():
    try:
        ent1_value = int(ent1.get())
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir solo números enteros.")
    else:
        if ent1_value == 1:
            vsismorresistente()
        elif ent1_value == 2:
            vperf_suelos()
        elif ent1_value == 3:
            vz_sismica()
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir la opción correcta")

def salir():
    vprincipal.destroy()

def vsismorresistente():
    vprincipal.withdraw()
    v_sism_rres = tk.Toplevel(vprincipal)
    v_sism_rres.title("ZONAS SISMORRESISTENTE")
    v_sism_rres.geometry("550x500+0+0")
    v_sism_rres.configure(background = "light sky blue")

def vperf_suelos():
    vprincipal.withdraw()
    v_suelos = tk.Toplevel(vprincipal)
    v_suelos.title("PERFILES DE SUELOS")
    v_suelos.geometry("550x500+0+0")
    v_suelos.configure(background = "light sky blue")

#Configuración de la ventana
vprincipal = tk.Tk()
vprincipal.title("SISMICIDAD")
vprincipal.geometry("550x500")
vprincipal.configure(background="light sky blue")

#ETIQUETAS:
#Menu Principal:
...

#ENTRADAS:
#Menu Principal:
ent1 = tk.Entry(vprincipal)
ent1.pack(pady = 1, ipady = 5)

#BOTONES:
#Boton para abrir opciones:
botonmenu = tk.Button(vprincipal, text = "Aceptar", fg = "black", command = menu)
botonmenu.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

botonsalir = tk.Button(vprincipal, text = "Salir", fg = "black", command = salir)
botonsalir.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

vprincipal.mainloop()
```

Comment: Listo!!!, me resultó.